# Different versions of MS SQL Server between remote ditribution Database and Publisher

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I need to set up a mechanism for transactional replication with "n" publishers and a subcriber. In this way I thought of putting a single database ditribution.
I would like to know if there are problems between versions of ditribution and publishers; for example, I can have a publisher created with MSSQL 2005 and distribution database created in MSSQL 2012?

Thanks,

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your needs have been anticipated: [MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Quoting the article:

> For all types of replication, the Distributor version must be no
>   earlier than the Publisher version. (Frequently, the Distributor is
>   the same instance as the Publisher.)
>
> For transactional replication, a Subscriber to a transactional
>   publication can be any version within two versions of the Publisher
>   version.

It would seem that your topology meets the requirements. Build it in test though to make sure you don't have any surprises.